# IntegrityError: column user_id is not unique in django tastypie test unit

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tastypie

I have an estrange error testing a resourcemodel in tastypie.

I have this test

```
class LocationResourceTest(ResourceTestCase):
    # Use ``fixtures`` & ``urls`` as normal. See Django's ``TestCase``
    # documentation for the gory details.
    fixtures = ['admin_user.json']

    def runTest(self):
        super(LocationResourceTest, self).runTest()


    def setUp(self):
        super(LocationResourceTest, self).setUp()

        # Create a user.
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='johndoe',email='johndoe@example.com',password='password')
        # Create an API key for the user:
        ApiKey.objects.create(user=self.user)

    def get_credentials(self):
        return self.create_apikey(username=self.user.username, api_key=self.user.api_key.key)

    def test_create_apikey(self):
        # Try api key authentication using ResourceTestCase.create_apikey().
        credentials = self.get_credentials()
        resp = self.api_client.get('/api/v1/location/',authentication=credentials,format='json')
        self.assertHttpOK(resp)

    def test_get_list_unauthorzied(self):
        pass
```

When I execute the test,I get the following error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_list_unauthorzied (geolocation.tests.api.LocationResourceTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/phantomis/Memoria/smartaxi_server/geolocation/tests/api.py", line 24, in setUp
    ApiKey.objects.create(user=self.user)
  File "/Users/phantomis/Virtualenvs/django-memoria/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 137, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/phantomis/Virtualenvs/django-memoria/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 377, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/phantomis/Virtualenvs/django-memoria/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.12_alpha-py2.7.egg/tastypie/models.py", line 47, in save
    return super(ApiKey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phantomis/Virtualenvs/django-memoria/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 463, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/Users/phantomis/Virtualenvs/django-memoria/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 551, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/phantomis/Virtualenvs/django-memoria/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 203, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/phantomis/Virtualenvs/django-memoria/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1593, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/phantomis/Virtualenvs/django-memoria/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 912, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/phantomis/Virtualenvs/django-memoria/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 344, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: column user_id is not unique
```

The error is in the method "test_get_list_unauthorzied" , is weird because if i comment that method, my test pass  (that method is completely empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setUp` is run for each of the `test_*` methods you have. When you comment out the empty test case, `setUp` is only run once. With the other `test_*` method not commented out, `setUp` is run twice, and this is how the uniqueness constraint gets violated.

I would create a `tearDown` method that deletes the user and api key you created in the other test case.